# GetLastError пишет что все хорошо, но CreateWindowEx возвращает 0

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Код:

```
int Window::Create() {
    WNDCLASSEX wcex{};
    auto szWindowClass = _T("Scream2DEngineWindow");

    auto hInstance = GetModuleHandle(nullptr);
    auto hIcon = LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style          = CS_DBLCLKS;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = hIcon;
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = nullptr;
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = hIcon;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex)) {
        return 1;
    }

    auto hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, szWindowClass, "Title", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 500, 100, HWND_DESKTOP, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);
    std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    if (!hWnd) {
        return 2;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    return 0;
}
```

В консоль выводит "0" (GetLastError), но функция возвращает 2, то есть hWnd == 0.

В чем ошибка?

Comment: Проверьте возвращённый `hWnd` с помощью `IsWindow()`. Если HWND не нулевой (а вы сами писали, что  `hWnd` равен двум), вполне возможно, что просто система выдаёт вам такой дескриптор, и так как бы и должно быть.

Comment: @ScreamTV5, перед тем, как вернуть `HWND` из `CreateWindowEx`, будет несколько раз вызван `WndProc`. Приложите к вопросу содержимое этой функции, это может прояснить ситуацию.

Answer (score 0):

GetLastError надо вызывать сразу же.

```
auto hWnd = CreateWindowEx(..);
auto err = GetLastError();
std::cout << err << std::endl;
```

Comment: Это ничего не меняет как был 0 так и остался ):